# Detect properties which cause the exception in ExpressMapper

Tags: asp.net, datamapper

Is there a way to detect which property caused the exception while Mapping using Express Mapper?

Comment: Hi Rahul, what kind of exception do you receive?

Comment: Hey George! There are some properties for which I get the string.format exception(due of some conversion issue or something else), but the problem is that I am not able to figure out which property has caused the error without looking at the data. I mean if I can know which property mapping caused the error.

Comment: any solution to this ?